# How do I install Pandas on windows(32bit)

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip

I have tried to install pandas as like procudure...

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

>pip freeze
numpy==1.11.1rc1
pytz==2016.4

>pip install "pandas-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"
pandas-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Why cannot I install pandas ?

Answer (score 2):

It's highly recommended to use the [anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#id2) distribution on windows. See also [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/#best-way-to-install) on the matter.

If you install via `pip` you will need compilers for part of the code ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-from-pypi)) which can be tricky to install on windows. Anaconda avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the version of pip you are using is outdated. Upgrade pip using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and you should be able to install pandas